# datefield does not show today date in html form even if datetime.date.today is specified

Tags: django, datefield

I am using a datefied in my form and html form to render it. i want the date field to be non-editable todays date, but it shows the datepicker. Could anyone please help

model:

```py
Dataset_Creation_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
```

HTML:

```
<label for="field3"><span>Date of Dataset Creation <span class="required">*</span></span><input class="input-field" name="Dataset_Creation_Date" value="" type="date"/></label>
```

View:

```
 Dataset_Creation_Date = request.POST["Dataset_Creation_Date"]
```

Comment: Is that your actual template? You don't seem to have any template variables in there; how are you expecting it to show any date?

Comment: I am sorry i dont know to answer your question, i am using a bootstrap html template to create the form. Where should i use the template variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `type="date"` to not get the date picker
2. Add `readonly` to just before the closing tag of the `input`.
3. Add a template variable to the value section of the input.
4. Format it to your specifications using `date:"D d M Y"`. You can learn more about it from the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

The code which meets all your needs (subject to customization):

```
<label for="field3"><span>Date of Dataset Creation <span class="required">*</span></span><input class="input-field" name="Dataset_Creation_Date" value=" {{your_date|date:"D d M Y"}}"readonly></label>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it just shows an empty box. the date is not shown --     <label for="field3"><span>Date of Dataset Creation <span class="required">*</span></span><input name="Dataset_Creation_Date" value=" {{a.Dataset_Creation_Date|date:"D d M Y"}}" readonly></label>

Comment: Can you add your view to the question?

Comment: you mean the views.py??

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: any answers to get the today date?

Comment: ` Dataset_Creation_Date = request.POST["Dataset_Creation_Date"]
` is this actually your view? This is not how you access a database.

Comment: Thanks, sorted. I just had to add  value={% now "Y-m-d" %} type="date" in the html field

Comment: Excellent. Glad 2 help.